# Is it possible to shut down a site and then reuse the old URL on a new site?

Tags: web-hosting, url

I am creating a web site for a friend's business. He already has a site, but it is a wizard-created site hosted free by Yahoo. I am creating am ASP.NET site from scratch. He wants to retain his URL - is that possible? Can he "release" the current URL (shut down that site) and then "reuse" it in the guise of the new site?

Comment: Is this a URL a domain name owned by your friend, or is it a URL on a Yahoo owned domain?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's Yahoo-hosted.

I see this in the page source:

<meta name="generator" content="Yahoo! SiteBuilder/2.6/1.6.0_05-ea">


<noscript><img src="http://visit.webhosting.yahoo.com/visit.gif?us1382641337" alt="setstats" border="0" width="1" height="1"></noscript>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the URL of the page is controlled by Yahoo, then you only have as much control as Yahoo allows.  You'll want to create the new site on a new domain name that gives you the control.

When you move the site to a new domain, implement redirects so that visitors that know about the old site can get to the new site.  Yahoo site builder doesn't have many redirect options.  Here is [a report from somebody that wants to move away from it to different hosting and asks how to redirect](http://www.cevx.me/net/site-built-with-yahoo-site-builder-move-to-another-hosting-remove-the-water-mark.html).  The answer:

> There is currently no redirect feature for Yahoo! Web Hosting plans, but you can use an HTML meta refresh...

So you would edit every HTML file on the old site and add a line in the `<head>` section like:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
```

Where you replace `example.com` with the domain name of your new site.

Answer (score 3):

If he purchased the domain name through a registrar, like Register.com,  then yes.  He can retain his URL  If he is using a domain name tied to Yahoo (username.yahoo.com....just an example URL not actually in the format of Yahoo) and the new site will not be hosted by Yahoo, then the answer is no.   He cannot "release" the current URL and reuse it.